# How can I make this question better?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628133/c-sharp-class-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-1-arguments) is getting some bad votes. I have corrected it several times and have learned a lot from it but it is not improving people's perception of it. I hope you can help me understand how I can make it better or what I did wrong.

Comment: It'd get an upvote from me (practically) automatically if it had the smallest complete program that showed your problem. I.e. everything including a `main()` needed to copy and paste into an IDE and see the exact same error on my system.

Comment: Maybe because it is a basic question and is asked many times? (disclaimer: I don't know anything about C#, and I haven't looked whether it has been asked before).

Comment: +1 from me, happy :)

Comment: I see that Jon Skeet and his legion of sock puppets are hard at work on that question. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there powerful users that influence the votes of people?

Comment: Jon knows how to hit the sweet spot between obscurity and banality.  Also note the `:P` after my last comment.

Comment: Remember too that someone may have down-voted your original answer, and has no way to know now that you have "corrected it several times." It still seems to be a basic question to me, but unless the previous down-voters have some reason to come back and check, their vote is going to stay the way it started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original error message told you *exactly what to do*, but you asked a question on StackOverflow instead; that gained some downvotes, I imagine. Then you edited to say that the solution that *every reader knows is correct* "did not help", which is quite frustrating, since of course we all know it *must* help, and that surely earned some more downvotes.

I think unfortunately the truth is that there's a certain level of question that *can't* be made into a good question; this is very basic programming language material, and questions like this just aren't appropriate on StackOverflow. I would say that a good rule of thumb is that you can't ask for help with anything you would learn in the first few chapters of an introductory textbook on a language.

Comment: Thanks @ErnestFriedman-Hill, instead of deleting the question, I have further edited it to show that I understood things a little bit more. I suppose there are people out there like me that might have difficulties with some concepts (maybe not everything though) and would be happy to see the replies to this very basic question which is why I asked how I could make the question more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry my answer sounds a little harsh; the truth is that this community just isn't very accepting of beginner questions. There are other forums that are more accepting of them: http://www.coderanch.com is one.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the question is getting down-votes because it doesn't show any search effort, and/or it is not useful to future readers.

What you should have done was said in the error message, and you don't report what happened when you tried adding the constructor; you say, "it did not help" without saying what exactly happened, and in which way what you get was different from what you expected.

Comment: Thank you @Kiamlaluno, I have changed this part, trust me a lot of search went into it (most of my afternoon). Will try to communicate this better.

Comment: I have changed the title to reflect more specificity too